# How to change the height of ExpandableListView when group is expanded

Tags: android, android-layout

How to change the height of ExpandableListView when group is expanded/collapsed?

I want to change the height of ExpandableListView to fit the height of its content, so that the view will not scroll inside itself.

this is the layout for main activity.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="jp.foo.android.activity.FooActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and this is a layout for the fragment of the main activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="jp.foo.android.fragment.FooFragment"
    android:background="@color/category_bg">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/subtitle_question_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/subtitle_category"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/category_list_bg_shape"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:minHeight="300dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/category_list_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/category_list"
            android:transcriptMode="normal">

        </ExpandableListView>
        </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the actual layout.
ExpandableListView will scroll inside when it has too many contents.
I want to scroll whole screen. Not only scroll view, but with header.
[image: layout sample]

Comment: if you set its height to WRAP_CONTENT it shouldn't scroll, nor you'd need to change heights on expand/contract

Comment: @rupps check out the question. I added my layout. I have already tried wrap_content, but that didn't help me :(

Comment: set the parent framelayout height to match_parent so its big enough. ExpandableList will scroll if elements dont fit. Also check if this is your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106471/android-disable-auto-scroll-in-expandable-list-view

Comment: it would help if you post a screenshot to figure out your layout

Comment: @rupps screenshot added.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar issue putting everything into a Header. I was close to solving it the traditional ways (ie. nesting layouts, weights, ...) but I felt the solution was pretty dirty, requiring overriding methods such as onGroupClick etc... to disable the ExpandableListView's scroll, while the header thing was clean and worked flawlessly for me.

So if you want to try this approach, just put an `ExpandableListView` alone inside your fragment, and prepare the rest to be inserted as Header.

So in your fragment a full `ExpandableListView`:

```
 <ExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/category_list"
    android:transcriptMode="normal">
 </ExpandableListView>
```

Then create the layout **expandable_header.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="jp.foo.android.fragment.FooFragment"
    android:background="@color/category_bg">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/subtitle_question_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/subtitle_category"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/category_list_bg_shape"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:minHeight="300dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/category_list_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then inflate the header into the ExpandableListView:

```
.
.
.
View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.expandable_header, null);
expandableList.addHeaderView(view, null, false);
.
.
.
```

This way the header will scroll together with the `ExpandableListView`, as it's inside it.

BTW, your layout has redundant elements, for example the `FrameLayout` that contains only a `TextView`. You can use only the `TextView`. Also the `LinearLayout` with the `ProgressBar`, if you are not using an opaque background, you could put the `ProgressBar` alone. The less `ViewGroups` you use the better the layout will perform!

Comment: thanks, but in my case, the ExpandableListView has its own background texture(white background with border radius). In my understanding, if I use header ExpandableListView's background will be also applied to the header. so I thought I can't use this method. Or is there any workaround? BTW, thanks for the review of the layout!

Comment: ohhh ... i see.. then I guess this won't work for you, as the background will be applied to the header as well. You could set another background to the header, but no way the corners will be shown below it...